# Posted model is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel as following

```
  public class MetalStockAddVM
{
    public MetalStock MetalStock { get; set; }


    public MetalStockAddVM()
    {
        this.MetalStock=new MetalStock();
    }
}
```

Here is My controller

```
 public class MetalStockController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMetalStockRepository iMetalStockRepository;

    public MetalStockController(IMetalStockRepository iMetalStockRepository)
    {
        this.iMetalStockRepository = iMetalStockRepository;
    }

    // GET: MetalStock
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddMetalStock()
    {
        MetalStockAddVM addVm=new MetalStockAddVM();

        return View(addVm);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMetalStock([Bind(Include = "MetalStock")]MetalStockAddVM metalStock)
{
    MetalStockDto metalStockDto = new MetalStockDto();

    metalStockDto = Mapper.Map<MetalStock, MetalStockDto>(metalStock.MetalStock);

    iMetalStockRepository.Insert(metalStockDto);

    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home") ;
}

}
```

Here is my view

```
@model LearningSpike.Models.ViewModels.MetalStockAddVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMetalStock","MetalStock",FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MetalStock.MetalId)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MetalStock.MetalId)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MetalStock.GlobalMaterialId)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MetalStock.GlobalMaterialId)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MetalStock.Length)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MetalStock.Length)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MetalStock.ColourCode)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MetalStock.ColourCode)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MetalStock.QuantityInStock)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MetalStock.QuantityInStock)
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Create"/>


}
```

When I post the model that is passed to the controller action method is empty . 
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I am creating an architectural spike for the first time so I can learn a lot.Thus its my first time implementing all heavy stuff (DI , DTO's , REpositories etc.) . I am still struggling with putting things in right places.
Thanks!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `[Bind(Include = "MetalStock")]` and second rename `metalStock` to some something like `metalStockVm` and see does it works or not.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMetalStock(MetalStockAddVM metalStockVm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below one

change your model code like below

```
public class MetalStockAddVM
{

  public MetalStock MetalStock { get; set; }

}
```

And then change you Action method code for HTTPPOST in AddMetalStock as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMetalStock(MetalStockAddVM metalStock)
{
    MetalStockDto metalStockDto = new MetalStockDto();

    metalStockDto = Mapper.Map<MetalStock, MetalStockDto>(metalStock.MetalStock);

    iMetalStockRepository.Insert(metalStockDto);

     return RedirectToAction("Index","Home") ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that's how it was before and it didn't work too. Any other ideas?